# MPI Implimentation stalling after two passes

Tags: c, mpi

I'm rather new to MPI, so I'm not sure why this code isn't functioning as expected. The idea is to pass an integer to a random node and decrement it until is reaches 0. When I try to run it, it passes the integer twice and stalls. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you!

```
if (rank == 0)
{
  potato = rand() % 100 + size; // generate a random number between the number of processors and 100
  sendTo = rand() % (size - 1) + 1; // generate a number (not 0) to represent the process to send the potato to

  MPI_Send(&potato, 1, MPI_INT, sendTo, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // send the potato
}

else // any process other than 0
{

  MPI_Recv(&potato, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); //receive potato

  if (potato == -1) // check for termination int
    return;

  --potato; // decrement potato

  if (potato != 0)
  {
    do
    {
      sendTo = rand() % (size - 1) + 1; // send to a process 1 through size - 1
    } while (sendTo == rank || sendTo == 0); // make sure it won't send the potato to itself or 0

    printf("Node %d has the potato, passing to node %d.\n", rank, sendTo);
    MPI_Send(&potato, 1, MPI_INT, sendTo, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  }

  else // potato == 0
  {
    printf("Node %d is it, game over.\n", rank);

    potato = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++rank) // send termination message
      MPI_Send(&potato, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Potato: 44
Node 3 has the potato, Passing to node 2.
Node 2 has the potato, Passing to node 3.
```

Comment: Good first question! Try printing out the value of `potato` at each node; might reveal something. At any rate, it can't hurt.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! When I printed the value of potato, it behaved as expected.

Comment: Good - just wanted to rule out the stupid problems.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! please note such questions should include a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing some loop. In your example, for node 3 to received the patato a second time, `MPI_Recv` must be called once more.

```
if (rank == 0)
{
  potato = rand() % 100 + size; // generate a random number between the number of processors and 100
  sendTo = rand() % (size - 1) + 1; // generate a number (not 0) to represent the process to send the potato to

  MPI_Send(&potato, 1, MPI_INT, sendTo, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // send the potato
}

else // any process other than 0
{
  /* Here is the loop beginning, while patato is not -1, continue reading*/
  while (1)
  {
    MPI_Recv(&potato, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); //receive potato

    if (potato == -1) // check for termination int
      return;

    --potato; // decrement potato

    if (potato != 0)
    {
      do
      {
        sendTo = rand() % (size - 1) + 1; // send to a process 1 through size - 1
      } while (sendTo == rank || sendTo == 0); // make sure it won't send the potato to itself or 0

      printf("Node %d has the potato, passing to node %d.\n", rank, sendTo);
      MPI_Send(&potato, 1, MPI_INT, sendTo, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }

    else // potato == 0
    {
      printf("Node %d is it, game over.\n", rank);

      potato = -1;
      for (int i = 1; i < size; ++rank) // send termination message
        MPI_Send(&potato, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: strictly speaking, this is incorrect w.r.t. the MPI Standard since when the game is over, `MPI_Send()` to self is invoked before a recv has been posted, and that has the potential to cause a deadlock.